# How to automatically sync s3 bucket to a local folder using windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to have a replica of my s3 bucket in a local folder. it should be updated when a change occurs on the bucket.

Comment: Use file storage gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`aws cli s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command to copy ('synchronize') files from an Amazon S3 bucket to a local drive.

To have it update frequently, you could schedule it as a Windows **Scheduled Tasks**. Please note that it will be making frequent calls to AWS, which will incur API charges (`$0.005 per 1000 requests`).

Alternatively, you could **use utilities that 'mount' an Amazon S3 bucket as a drive** (Tntdrive, Cloudberry, Mountain Duck, etc). I'm not sure how they detect changes -- they possibly create a 'virtual drive' where the data is not actually downloaded until it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **rclone** and **Winfsp** to mount S3 as a drive.
Though this might not be a 'mount' in traditional terms.

You will need to setup a task scheduler for a continuous sync.

Example : https://blog.spikeseed.cloud/mount-s3-as-a-disk/